# simple way to create grouped stacked bar in R

Tags: r, plot

I have two 3x2 Matrices A, and B :

A:

```
          n2  n3
Part1     1   5
Part2     2   6
Part3     3   7
```

B:

```
          n2  n3   
Part1     5   1 
Part2     6   2   
Part3     7   3
```

and I want to create stacked bar based on the columns n2, n3 for A, and B and then group the stacked bar, such that n2 for A, and B are grouped together side-by-side and same for n3. This is what I have tried:

```
  d1 <- read.csv("A.csv", header=T, dec=".",sep = " ")
  d1 <- subset(d1, select = c(n2, n3))

  d2 <- read.csv("B.csv", header=T, dec=".",sep = " ")
  d2 <- subset(d2, select = c(n2, n3))

  d <- cbind(d1[,1],d2[,1],d1[,2],d2[,2])

  barplot(t(d), beside=T, ,col=c("lawngreen","firebrick","deepskyblue"),
          space=c(0,0,0.2,0))
```

and it produces:
[image]

Which bars are grouped, but there is no stacking, and colors are mis-used as well. And when I change the barplot to the following, it produces the below plot:

```
   barplot(t(d), col=c("lawngreen","firebrick","deepskyblue"), 
           space=c(0,0,0.2,0))
```

[image]

In which bars are wrongly stacked, and wrongly grouped. I appreciate it if you help me to resolve this as I am new to R :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`barplot()` groups the bars using the columns of your input matrix. Using this as the data:

```
> (d <- matrix((1:7)[-4],ncol=2)[,c(1,2,2,1)])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    5    1
[2,]    2    6    6    2
[3,]    3    7    7    3
```

You can just take off the transpose from your previous code:

```
barplot(d, col=c("lawngreen","firebrick","deepskyblue"), space=c(0,0,0.2,0))
```

[image: stacked bar plot]

Comment: Aha great. A quick question, is there a way to assign n2, and n3 to the x-axis?

Comment: You can set the `names.arg` in barplot, but it will center under a bar, not the group of bars. To center up the labels correctly you would probably be happier redoing the plot in ggplot2

Comment: But I don't know ggplot :/